# Go accessing nested items in interface

Tags: go, nested

I'm trying to understand what is the best practice for accessing nested items inside an interface.

In the screenshot below, you can see the value of `eventObj`
[image]

How do I access `display_login` field?
(`eventObj -> actor -> display_login`)

I've tried multiple ways, but without success. for example:

When I try the below type assertion:
`eventObj["actor"].([map[string]interface{}])`

I get an error of: `syntax error: unexpected ), expecting type (exit status 2)`

Comment: Use a [type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions). Similar to what you're already doing, just use the actual dynamic type that's stored in the interface, rather than the interface itself.

Comment: Please try `dataMap:=actorObj.([map[string]interface{}]) displayLogin:=dataMap["display_login"].(string) `

Comment: "Best practice" is not to use the empty interface for such stuff.

Comment: Thx for the comments above, I'm still having issues here and I've updated the question above.
As you can see, I'm a newbie to Go and struggling a bit...